# Config apache server on mac Sierra

Tags: php, macos, apache, config, macos-sierra

I have a weird issue with localhost on my Mac. I'm trying to setup Apache server, but I'm just stuck with the localhost. So on a new tab if I type in localhost and press enter, it shows 'It works'. But if I then refresh the page, it only disconnects and says 'The site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect.' I've followed all the steps in several tutorials about setting this up but nothing solves this issue. Any thoughts?
BTW - I upgrade php to php7

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about how to configure your system or environment, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/, or perhaps http://AskDifferent.com/ as your question may be macOS-specific. I'm voting to close this question, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue.  Do you have swap enabled?

Comment: @Bluebaron I am not sure.. what is swap..?

Comment: Do you have this running on your local system or in a virtual machine?

Comment: Just figure it out. I was needed to uncomment the php5 in the .conf file.
Tanx !